# how to fix position of items in listview after scroll in android

Tags: android, listview

I have created a dynamic listview in android app.

each item of listview has different values.
i have used dynamic edittexts for product.
But when i scroll up or down values are changing their positions.

my code as,

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.addeditem, null);

                holder.qty = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editTextqty);
                holder.ProductName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prodname);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } 
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.qty.setId(position);
            try
            {
                tempQty = MyArrayList.get(position).get("qty");

                Log.i("Test", position+" tempQty= "+tempQty);

                holder.qty.setText(tempQty);
            } 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                holder.qty.setText("");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.i("Test","["+ position+"] Qty = " +holder.qty.getText().toString());

            holder.ProductName.setText(mproductName.get(position).get("MainProduct").toString());

            holder.qty.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
            {
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
                {
                    if (!hasFocus)
                    {
                        final int position = v.getId();
                        final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;

                        String qty = Caption.getText().toString();
                        String name = mproductName.get(position).get("MainProduct").toString();
                        String itemcode = mproductName.get(position).get("ItemCode").toString();

                        try 
                        {
                            if(!qty.equalsIgnoreCase("")||!qty.equalsIgnoreCase(null))
                            {
                                HashMap<String, String> hashMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
                                hashMap.put("name",name);
                                hashMap.put("itemcode",itemcode);
                                hashMap.put("qty",qty);
                                MyArrayList.add(position,hashMap);

                            }
                        } 
                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }
```

Screen Shot..

[image: There are dynamic qty edittexts]

please help me.

Comment: Can you post logs and screenshot of your app?

Comment: After SCroll these 55 , 55 , 77 Changes their location to other products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the data set changes in the adapter you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged();`. In your case you need call here

```
    try {
        if (!qty.equalsIgnoreCase("") || !qty.equalsIgnoreCase(null)) {
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hashMap.put("name", name);
            hashMap.put("itemcode", itemcode);
            hashMap.put("qty", qty);
            MyArrayList.add(position, hashMap);

            notifyDataSetChanged(); //add this line change
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**IMPT** : `setOnFocusChangeListener` is called only when the focus on the EditText changes. What I want to say is while editing a EditText if you scroll down/up (view is invisible) that time your dataset won't get updated, when u scroll down/up you will get the old data in EditText.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using a different view holder for every line, and that when recycling your list item views your holders are shuffled togheter.

You can see this simply adding a **final int position** field to your holder, where to store the getView position parameter; debugging, you will see what happen.

So, you can't use holders to store your quantity values

Example:-

public View getView(final int position, View convertView,final ViewGroup parent) {

```
final ViewHolder holder;
LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

if (convertView == null) {

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addeditem, null);

    holder = new ViewHolder();
```

Comment: What should i do after adding final int position in holder?i mean - what should i change in getview.please explain with example code.

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of the holder. It is just to increase performance with long lists and complicated item layouts. Try to make it work without the holder stuff before you introduce any optimizations. Probably your problems will go away if you remove the holder.